# How can I print an error message if the value is < 250

Tags: java

I have this code where somebody can choose a ppm value and it calculates the `fanControl` value.

```java
static int fanControl(int ppm) {
      
    if (ppm < 401 && ppm > 250 ) {
        return 0;   
    } else if (ppm >= 401 && ppm < 800) {
        return (ppm - 400)/4;
    } else if (ppm >= 800) {
        return 100;
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

What do I have to do that the program prints an error message and stops calculating if the person who chooses the ppm value, chooses something less than 250.

Comment: I'd throw an `IllegalArgumentException`, but that's really for you to decide how to treat invalid input. In your case returning -1 could be equally effective to signal an invalid input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Federico

Your solution will depend on how you want to handle invalid input

Just change `return;` to `return -1;`

Then, whenever/wherever you call `fanControl(X)`, just surround it with a conditional:

```
if (fanControl(X) == -1){
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("ppm value must be at least 250");
} else {
   //Do whatever you were planning to do
}
```

Also, make sure your `ppm > 250` is changed to `ppm >= 250` if you want to include `250` as valid input

Comment: so i tried it and it worked.. but the problem is that it still prints the fanControl value (-1) but it shouldnt if the error message appears

Comment: @Joel I can't see the rest of your code, so i don't know how/where you're printing fanControl's value